# Using mock.patch to disable a function behavior

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a function adding subscription for my users. At the end of this function,
an instruction check the subscriptions and do some stuff with patron if necessary.
For my testing, I need to skip this last instruction ; so I tried to use `mock.patch`
but despite all my tries, the code is always executed (and my tests failed)

---

**mymodule/classes.py**

```py
class User:

    def add_subscription(self, start_date, end_date):
        subscriptions = self.get('subscriptions', [])
        subscriptions.append({'start': start_date, 'end': end_date})
        self['subscriptions'] = subscriptions
        check_subscriptions(self)  # <-- skip this instruction for unitesting


def check_subscriptions(user):
    print("Not need to print for unitesting")
    # next doing more stuff...
    ...
```

---

**tests/user_unitest.py**

```py
import mock
from mymodule.classes import User
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

...

def test_subscriptions(user_with_no_subscription_fixture):
    user = user_with_no_subscription_fixture
    start = datetime.now()
    end = start + timedelta(days=10)
    user.add_subscription(start, end)
    ...
```

How can I use the `@mock.patch` (or other mock function) to don't enter into the
`User.check_subscriptions` methods ?

---

### **What I tried (and didn't work)**

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.classes.check_subscriptions')
def test_subscriptions(user_with_no_subscription_fixture):
    user = user_with_no_subscription_fixture
    start = datetime.now()
    end = start + timedelta(days=10)
    user.add_subscription(start, end)
```

```
def test_subscriptions(user_with_no_subscription_fixture):
    with mock.patch('mymodule.classes.check_subscriptions'):
        user = user_with_no_subscription_fixture
        start = datetime.now()
        end = start + timedelta(days=10)
        user.add_subscription(start, end)
```

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.classes.check_subscriptions', MagicMock())
def test_subscriptions(user_with_no_subscription_fixture):
    user = user_with_no_subscription_fixture
    start = datetime.now()
    end = start + timedelta(days=10)
    user.add_subscription(start, end)
```

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.classes.check_subscriptions', side_effect=...)
def test_subscriptions(user_with_no_subscription_fixture):
    user = user_with_no_subscription_fixture
    start = datetime.now()
    end = start + timedelta(days=10)
    user.add_subscription(start, end)
```

thanks for your always usefull help

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `@mock.patch('mymodule.classes.User.check_subscriptions')`, with `side_effect`, `with mock.patch(...)` inside my test function, ...

Comment: Please update the *question* with *exactly* how you tried.

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies in the code: you define `User` in `mymodule.user.py` (I guess you mean `mymodule/user.py`), but import it from `mymodule.classes`. Also `object` is incorrectly written (and incidentally not needed) and the `self` argument missing in the function - please copy and paste the relevant part of _the actual code_ here, otherwise it is difficult to see where the problem lies.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen You're right. I tried to simplify my code to keep it understandable. My entire relevant code is more than 300 lines. Despite my previous copy errors (now corrected) the problem stay the same ;-) Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Ok, better :) Now you patch `my module.user` instead of `mymodule.classes`. Is that also a typo?